# how to rename or change file name case on the same location in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, file, rename

I am working on application which required me to change the filename case retaining the original filename as it is For Example: need to change abc.txt => (ABC.txt or Abc.txt or abc.TXT or abc.Txt) filename as well as its extension can be change in same way. I tried to use the NSFileManager

```
- (BOOL)movePath:(NSString *)source toPath:(NSString *)destination handler:(id)handler
```

But it didn't change the case,Please let me know how i can change the filename or extension case only in objective-c or c function, if it can be use in objective-c.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this helps:
http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/208834-possible-bug-in-nsfilemanager-moveitematpath-topath-error.html